# Django and JSON/AJAX testing

Tags: python, json, ajax, django

I tried looking around for an answer and gave it a great many tries, but there's something strange going on here. I got some functions in my view that operate on JSON data that comes in via AJAX. Currently I'm trying to do some unit testing on these.

In my test case I have:

```
kwargs = {'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
url = '/<correct_url>/upload/'
data = {
                "id" : p.id
}

c = Client()
response = c.delete(url, data, **kwargs)

content_unicode = response.content.decode('utf-8')
content = json.loads(content_unicode)
```

p.id is just an integer that comes from a model I'm using.

I then have a function that is being tested, parts of which looks like follows:

```
def delete_ajax(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    print (request.body)
    body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
    print (body_unicode)
    body_json = json.loads(body_unicode)
```

The first print statement yields:

```
.....b"{'id': 1}"
```

The other one:

```
{'id': 1}
```

and finally I get an error for fourth line as follows:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

What's going wrong here? I understand that correct JSON format should be `{"id": 1}` and that's what I'm sending from my test case. But somewhere along the way single-quotes are introduced into the mix causing me head ache.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a json string to `Client.delete()`, not a Python dict:

```
kwargs = {'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
url = '/<correct_url>/upload/'
data = json.dumps({
 "id" : p.id
 })

c = Client()
response = c.delete(url, data, **kwargs)
```

You should also set the content-type header to "application/json" and check the content-type header in your view but that's another topic.

Comment: Thanks! I almost got it before your answer, but you were still faster. The content-type checking is the next thing to take care of :)